# Extracting names, enclosed in double quotes from string to List

Tags: java

I need to extract names from below String.

```
["AAA","BBB"....]

NOTE: '[',']' are part of string.
```

Comment: What is input and expected output? And what you have tried so far and getting current result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you showed us is literal string data, you could try:

```java
String input = "[\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\"]";
input = input.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "");
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split(",")));
System.out.println(parts);
```

This prints:

```
[AAA, BBB, CCC]
```

The logic here strips off the square brackets from the input strings, removes all double quotes, and then splits on comma to generate an array of strings, which is later converted into a list.